# Raspberry Pi won't boot after update Ubuntu Mate

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

Updated Ubuntu Mate on RPi 4 8GB. It rebooted and ran.
Subsequent boots fail with messages:

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: Invalid magic at start of compressed archive
spi=bcm 2835 fc204000.spi could not get clock -517
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar errors have gotten a variety of responses. None of which applied here. So I burned a fresh image of Mate on a micro SD card and it now works.
Thanks, JPB

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/131731)

Comment: Well I am the author. Sorry about the confusion. I'm fairly new to stack exchange. It's just that similar errors in past have not gotten satisfactory answers either. Rather than dwell on the issue I did the "sensible" workaround for a Raspberry Pi and and burned a new OS image. That worked and showed that the update was probably the error source.